# Why does adding eventlistner to my dynamically created images alle fire at pageload after updating to Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

I had this function working perfectly in Angular 7. I create some icons which , when clicked fire showRel with the id i set for that image.  After updating to Angular 8 in stead of firing when i click the image, all  the showRel gets fired for each image on page refresh .. Any idea what i am doing wrong ?

```
 plot(id,mood,x,y,dt){ 
    var img = document.createElement('img'); 
    img.src ="/assets/img/"+ mood+ ".png"; 
    img.style.position ="absolute";
    img.style.left ="" + x + "px";
    img.style.top = "" + y  +"px";
    img.id=id;
    img.style.width ="30px"; 
    img.setAttribute('mood', mood);   
    // tried both of these ... : Not working as from ANGULAR 8
    img.onclick =  this.showRel(id);         
 // img.addEventListener('click', this.showRel(id));

    document.getElementById('graph').appendChild(img);     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a zindex of 5 to the images, now it works like a dream:

```
plot(id,mood,x,y,dt){ 
    var img = document.createElement('img'); 
    img.src ="/assets/img/"+ mood+ ".png"; 
    img.style.position ="absolute";
    img.style.zIndex ="5";  // ADDED THIS TO MAKE IT WORKING !!!
    img.style.left ="" + x + "px";
    img.style.top = "" + y  +"px";
    img.id=id;
    img.style.width ="30px"; 
    img.setAttribute('mood', mood);   
    img.addEventListener('click', this.showRel(id));
    document.getElementById('graph').appendChild(img);     
}
```

Hope it helps someone....Im not 100% sure the problem was caused by updating from Angular 7 to 8...